# Distributed weblogic server environment using same DB2 database and schema but obtain different sequence values for an OpenJPA entity

Tags: db2, weblogic, openjpa

I am using a distributed server environment with Weblogic 12 servers set up on 2 different hosts.
The 2 hosts point to the same DB2 database schema. Same application EAR is deployed on both servers.
I am using OpenJPA 1.2 to map a class to a particular database table. On the entity I have defined GenerationType.SEQUENCE, mapped to relevant sequence name in database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ART", uniqueConstraints=@Unique(columnNames="TITLE"))
@SequenceGenerator(name="ArticleSeq", sequenceName="ART_SEQ", initialValue=1, 
allocationSize=1)
public class Article {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="ArticleSeq") 
private long id;

...
}
```

The value of Sequence 'ART_SEQ' in database is currently 150. All requests which get processed at server A, get the correct next value for the sequence, that is 151. But, the requests which get processed at server B, get the next value for the sequence starting from 1.

I am not using OpenJPA DateCache. Also I read that, only starting with OpenJPA 2.2.0, sequence values are cached in the jvm memory.

What could be the reason why on server B, all the DB insertions use the sequence value starting from 1, which fails the insertion due to contraint violation?

Comment: Have you tried to restart server B? Perhaps it has been running a long time, and is holding onto an old (and no longer valid) batch of keys.

Comment: Both the servers were setup 2 weeks before. Server A and B were restarted  this week, after redeploying the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after restarting server B.